# ImportError: No module named pygame

Tags: python, pygame, importerror

I am trying to run a python program on a raspberry pi that uses `pygame` and I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newTtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pygame import mixer
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: How did you install pygame? Do you have multiple Python versions installed? If yes, check out if you have installed pygame for the correct version.

Comment: It is on my computer, I typed in the command: python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user

Comment: This works. However I believe that my issue is when I try to install it on the raspberry pi using: sudo apt-get install python-pip , I get a
"Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'". The only version of python I have downloaded is Python 2.7.13.

Comment: Try running sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade -y then try install pygames again with the command you tried before

Comment: I think the problem is that it is not connected to wifi. I did ping www.google.com and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

in the command line type

```
sudo apt-get install pygame
```

that should install it, because pygame isn't already installed on the Raspberry Pi/Debian.